# Annoyed with lack of debugging features in CodeIgniter. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing a lot of development with CodeIgniter these days and I am extremely irriated with the lack of debugging features in CI.

It does throw errors if a view file is missing and so on. But when I forget to put a semicolon somewhere it simply does not throw any error.

I ensured now and again that error level is set to E_ALL, I checked the logs but nowhere the syntax errors are getting captured. This wastes a lot of my time.

Comment: CodeIgniter certainly will report syntax errors (it is just PHP after all) but you need to have PHP configured to do so.

Comment: please tell me specifically what config changes I need to make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that the best way to deal with this situation is to use an editor with PHP syntax checking. From the command line you can also run

```
php -l filename.php
```

to syntax check your file.

You can turn on syntax error reporting in your php.ini, but it is disabled by default.

set

```
 display_errors on
```

along with your

```
 error_reporting E_ALL
```

Comment: Yes i use http://tools.sopili.net/php-syntax-check/ But am I doing something wrong or is it the case with CI ?

Comment: You are right, it is just the case with CI, it won't be able to determine these things - It never gets to the point of running with a syntax error in the code.

Comment: It's not the frameworks job to ensure that your code is free from an error such as a missing semi-colon.  This should always give you a fatal parse error as the file is not syntaxically correct.

Comment: @simnom yes I expect a fatal error and I will be thankful if that happens. But all I get is a blank page.

Comment: still having issues? you have a link or some code we can explore?

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to use an IDE like Eclipse in debug mode to step through the code. Once Eclipse is set up properly, it can step through trace points and display the status of each operation, line by line. It can be a real time saver.

Answer (score 0):

If you have actual syntax errors in your PHP, I don't think there's any way for a PHP framework, such as CodeIgniter, to catch them.